# Write a method that takes an integer argument and returns the number of times that integer occurs in the list

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I am complete new to Linked List in Java, and having trouble finding any help on this.

Write a method that takes an integer argument and returns the number of times that integer
occurs in the list

```
public class LinkedList
{

private class Node
{
public int data; 
public Node next;
public Node( int datum, Node n ) {data = datum; next = n;}
}

private Node head; // the head of the list
LinkedList() { head = null; }

}
```

Comment: I didn't even know linked lists existed in Java. I loved learning them in C++. As I don't know linked lists in Java, maybe I could propose a solution with some pseudo code. I would think you just need to:
`-Compare number in question
-If true, ++
-Else move to next node`
Sorry if this is pointless for you.

Comment: Do you really have to implement a linked list? Or just use the one already provided?

Comment: Use one already provided. I think I figured it out though.

public int count( int searchFor ) {
 
 if (head == null){ return 0; }
 
 int count = 0;
 
 Node node = head;
  
    while(head.next != null){
     node = node.next;
       if (node.data == searchFor){
        count++;
       }
    }
    return count;

    }

Comment: @Ducksauce88 Linked Lists exist in every OO language (and even some not).

Comment: I really hate to see embedded classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int count(final int n){
    int count = 0;
    Node node = head;
    while(node != null){
        if(node.data == n)
            ++count;
        node = node.next;
    }
    return count;
}
```